# Append divs with style using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I am creating html elements using JQuery and appending them to the document, but I was wondering how I might be able to do it with style using something like on this page where it describes the "swinging in" animation down towards the bottom of page. 
https://cssanimation.rocks/list-items/

I am using a setInterval method to append the divs one by one slowly, but I tried the method described in website, but it does not work.

```
timer = (setInterval(addprojectsNow, 1000));

function addprojectsNow(){
    console.log("FIRSTCLICK ADDPROJECTS", firstClick);
    console.log("PROJECTS LINKS OBJECT", projectLinks);

        let newProject = $('<div style="display: none;" class="col-md-6">').attr('id', count);
        let innerDiv = $('<div class="portfolio-item well">');
        let heroku = $('<a href="' + projectLinks[count].project.herokuLink + '"' + ' target="_blank" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12"><h4><b>' + projectLinks[count].project.heroku + '</b></h4></a>');
        let github = $('<a href="' + projectLinks[count].project.githubLink + '"' + ' target="_blank" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12"><b><h4>Github Link</b></h4></a>');
        let img = $('<img style="border: solid; border-width: thin; border-style: dashed;" class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="' + projectLinks[count].project.imgSRC + '"' + '>');
        innerDiv.append(heroku);
        innerDiv.append(github);
        innerDiv.append(img);
        newProject.append(innerDiv);



        $(newProject)addClass('show').appendTo('.portfolio-showcase').show('slow');


        return;
}
```

//The container the new `<divs>` are being appended to. The last nested divs has the '.swing' class.

```
<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center ">
                <h2>My Applications</h2>
                <hr class="medium bold">
                <div class="row portfolio-showcase swing">
```

/CSS

```
.swing {
  perspective: 500px;
}

.swing div.col-md-6 {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.64,.34,1.76);
}

.swing div.show {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.36,-0.64,.34,1.76);
}
```

Comment: Add class to your element while appending.

Comment: I forgot to add that in. I already tried adding the class '.show' to the divs that are being appended but it didnt seem to work

Comment: _"it didnt seem to work"_ Can you include `css` at Question, create stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: okay I updated with addclass 'show' part.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the item as you like before you append it

var newDiv = "

Comment: Yes, i tried adding the class 'show' before appending but it still did not work

Answer (score 0):

`$(newProject)addClass` you're missing a .

`$(newProject).addClass`

Answer (score 0):

There is some syntax issue :

$(newProject).addClass('show').appendTo('.portfolio-showcase').show('slow');

Please add the . just after $(newProject)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
setInterval(function(){ 

    var newProject = $('<div style="display: none;" class="col-md-6">').attr('id', count);
    var innerDiv = $('<div class="portfolio-item well">');
    var heroku = $('<a href="' + projectLinks[count].project.herokuLink + '"' + ' target="_blank" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12"><h4><b>' + projectLinks[count].project.heroku + '</b></h4></a>');
    var github = $('<a href="' + projectLinks[count].project.githubLink + '"' + ' target="_blank" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12"><b><h4>Github Link</b></h4></a>');
    var img = $('<img style="border: solid; border-width: thin; border-style: dashed;" class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="' + projectLinks[count].project.imgSRC + '"' + '>');
    innerDiv.append(heroku);
    innerDiv.append(github);
    innerDiv.append(img);
    newProject.append(innerDiv);

    newProject.addClass('show').appendTo('.portfolio-showcase').show('slow');

    return;

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You define the initial styles, then overwrite them with a class that you add via jQuery and the overwriting class uses `transition` to create the effect. But you need to add the class in a `setInterval` so that the element is added to the DOM with the initial style, *then* receives the new style to transition, otherwise the element will get the new class too fast and the transition won't fire. Here's a demo.

```js
$('button').on('click',function() {
  $newEl = $('<li>foo</li>');
  $('ul').append($newEl);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $newEl.addClass('show');
  })
})
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  background: #d1703c;
  border-bottom: 0 solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 2em;
  width: 10em;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.36, -0.64, 0.34, 1.76);
}

.show {
  height: 2em;
  border-width: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
}

ul { 
  perspective: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>

<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried adding class show before appending but same results. Where is the 'swing' class suppose to be set at? In your case ul?

Comment: @henhen yes, added to my demo.

Answer (score 0):

$(newProject).appendTo('.portfolio-showcase');
setTimeout(function(){$(newProject).addClass("show")},500)